# Is there a way to provide KafkaListener/topic-specific configuration via application.properties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When using Spring for Apache Kafka in a Spring Boot project, is there a way to configure different listeners via entries in `application.properties`?

For example, if I have separate listeners on topics `foo` and `bar`, can I have entries like:

```
spring.kafka.producer.foo.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.bar.value-serializer=some.other.Serializer
```

I thought I saw an example of this somewhere, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no support on the producer side, but you can do it on the consumer side (since 2.2.4). Please open a GitHub new feature issue and we can take a look at it.

For the consumer side, see the [properties attribute on the annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html#properties--)

```
@KafkaListener( ... properties={ "value.deserializer:${a.deserializer}", ... }, ...)

@KafkaListener( ... properties={ "value.deserializer:${b.deserializer}", ... }, ...)
```

You can set any arbitrary Kafka consumer properties there; they will supersede any properties with the same name defined in the consumer factory (if the consumer factory supports property overrides).

Comment: Thanks, Gary. I realize my question was a little confusing because I talked about Listeners but then used Producers/Serializers as the example. But I actually meant for both Consumers and Producers.

Comment: No problem; I guessed that; right now you would need to configure multiple `DefaultProducerFactory` beans (which can be populated with property values), but it shouldn't be too difficult for us to provide a mechanism to override producer properties for each `KafkaTemplate` or even something more sophisticated, such as by topic.